# How to pivot data on RDLC report?

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

My RDLC report is bound to a stored procedure which is returning data in this format:

SalesDeals     SalesPerc

---

Sale1              25%

Sale2              35%

Sale3              45%

Sale4              65%

On the report, I want to represent the bar chart as shown in the attached image. Is there a way to pivot the SalesDeals to columns.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to `pivot` data to do what you wish to do above. As you are using `rdlc` you just need to add a `chart` - and set its axis, series and data properties. The `rdlc` will do the work for you. The `Stored Procedure` that returns you the above `resultset` is perfect for the chart(one shown in the image above) u want to make.

Comment: ok. Just in case I pass a dynamic query to RDLC, is it able to recognize the columns?

Comment: It worked but it is not showing the Sales Deal names in the X-Axis.